# ReactNative - TextInput Cursor and text are disappeared when the number of lines reach to the certain level (around 20th line)

Tags: react-native, textinput

I use react native for my App(iOS), and it has an entry form where users can enter long text.
The following is my code, and basically, it works correctly.
But when I change the font size (iOS device level) to a smaller size, the cursor of this TextInput are disappeared when I reached the 20th line. (util 19th line, nothing wrong, but once enter line feed and come to 20th line, the cursor is disappeared).
After the cursor is gone, still I can continue to enter some text, and when I come to 21th line, all text at the 20th line comes back to be visible.

I suspect that line-height and the font size have something to do with this issue, but not sure.
I guess one of the solutions is to fix the font size so that the font size won't change even if I change my device font size, but it loses the convenience, so not happy to do that.

I would appreciate it if you could give me any advice!

```js
<Container style={style}>
  <ScrollView
    ref={scrollRef}
    style={{
      flex: 1,
    }}
    keyboardShouldPersistTaps="always"
    contentInset={{ bottom: 260 }}
  >
    <View
      style={{
        justifyContent: "flex-start",
      }}
    >
      <TextInput
        autoFocus
        multiline
        onFocus={onFocus}
        numberOfLines={5}
        scrollEnabled={false}
        placeholder={placeholder}
        textAlignVertical="top"
        value={value}
        allowFontScaling={false}
      />
    </View>
  </ScrollView>
</Container>;

const Container = styled.View`
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
`;

const MyTextInput = styled.TextInput`
  line-height: 26px;
  padding-bottom: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 0 32px;
`;
```

Comment: Did you try increasing the numberOfLines